# SAP Unicode: Offset exceed

Tags: unicode, abap

I got some account issues in the SCN so I make a attempt here.

We switched to Unicode and got some issues with that. `INFTY_TAB = PS+2.` This coding gets an error that "the offset + length is exceeding".

I found some hints but couldn't really figure out how to fix this. And even when I manage to fix those errors I got a new error called 'Iclude-Report %HR_P9002 not found'. The IT is still there so is there something else I can check?

Definition of PS:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF PS OCCURS 0.
*This indicates if a record was read with disabled authority check.
data:   authc_disabled(1) type c.
DATA:   TCLAS LIKE PSPAR-TCLAS.
        INCLUDE STRUCTURE PRELP.
DATA:   ACRCD LIKE SY-SUBRC.
DATA: END OF PS.
```

`TCLAS` is a char(1) field.

This is the part where the error pops up:

```
INFTY_TAB = PS+2.
```

Error: I had to translate so sorry for some mistakes that could appear.

> Offset and Length (=2432) exceed the length of the character based beginning (=2430) of the structure.

Comment: This is probably too brief for readers to be able to assist you. Can you show a relevant piece of code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I added some coding and the error below.

Comment: OK, please don't do that! You've added it as an answer, and it should be in the question. Use [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44042126/edit) please, and delete your answer.

Comment: Ok sorry for that. It's a bit hectic around here. Need to take a few minutes of break I think to get back in... though thanks for your help! Hope now I was able to post everything correct.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the length of INFTY_TAB. You have to explicitly set length:

```
INFTY_TAB = PS+2(length).
```

Official information is [here.](https://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/79/c55470b3dc11d5993800508b6b8b11/content.htm) The important point to note is that the inclusion of `SY-SUBRC` (which is an `INT4` field) places a limit to the range of fields you can access using this (discouraged) method of access.

> ASSIGN field+off TO  is generally forbidden from a syntactical
>   point of view since any offset <> 0 would cause the range to be
>   exceeded.

Although the sentence above is related to ASSIGN command, it is also valid for this situation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. With the help of this [PDF](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/b02d3594-ae48-2a10-83a7-89d369b708e5/Requirements%20of%20ABAP%20Programs%20in%20Unicode%20Systems.PDF) I created a type like `TYPES: BEGIN OF Z_PRELP.
        INCLUDE STRUCTURE PRELP.
TYPES: END OF Z_PRELP.`.

After that I included the type in my PS like: `INCLUDE TYPE z_prelp AS zz_prelp.`

The error doesn't show up anymore, but now I get an error that the include-report '%HR_P9002' is not found... The IT exists.

Comment: This is not related to the original unicode problem. Speak to some HR guy, 9002 seems to be a custom infotype, the include needs to be generated I think.

Comment: Ok thanks I will do that. I hope the adjustments I made will work after fixing this HR-Error. I will reply when everything works how I could fix it.